# I want to create directory and save image file but its name already exist its should have numbers indicating

Tags: python

I want to create directory from input:"imgdir" in same name  but its name already exist
it should have numbers indicating that it is the second directory like imgdir(2)/ and if input "imgdir" again it will make directory name imgdir(3)/

```
existing directory

dir-----|
        |-imgdir/


after make directory name "imgdir"

dir-----|
        |-imgdir/
        |-imgdir(2)/

after make directory name "imgdir" again

dir-----|
        |-imgdir/
        |-imgdir(2)/
        |-imgdir(3)/
```

and I want to save image and its name already exist it should have numbers indicating like making directory

```
existing image

dir-----|
        |-imgdir|-----/pic.jpg

after save(pic.jpg)

dir-----|
        |-imgdir|-------/pic.jpg
                        /pic(2).jpg    


after save(pic.jpg) again

dir-----|
        |-imgdir|-------/pic.jpg
                        /pic(2).jpg
                        /pic(3).jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [path module](https://www.guru99.com/python-check-if-file-exists.html), you'd have to check if the existing path exists.

So checking if the image exists, you'd check

```
# Check if the base path exists
save_path = "pic.jpg"

# Check if it exists and otherwise modify path
i = 2
while path.exists(save_path):
    save_path + "(" + i + ")"
    i += 1

# Write your file here
```

The same process you can use for the folders.